# Add custom config file when building with Haskell Stack

Tags: haskell, config, haskell-stack

I am currently learning Haskell and as an exercise programmed a simple RestAPI with Servant. This program doesn't use a database but writes to and reads from files.

The paths where the program should read and write are currently given via a custom configfile, e.g. "myconfig.ini" and I read this config with the [config.ini](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/config-ini) package.

This worked pretty well while developing locally, since I used `stack ghci` to run the main method and therefore the program. After being done with all the basic features I wanted to try and deploy it on an nginx server.

I simply copied the executable into nginx's `/http` folder like suggested [here](https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant/issues/469) and tried to execute it, where I ran into my problem. The config file is not in the same folder anymore and therefore can not be read anymore.

I am used to Java where the necessary files are usually part of the resulting archive, e.g. a `.war` file. Is it possible to achieve this in Haskell? And if not, what is the best practice regarding config files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to “package” your configuration files with your program that’s easy enough to do; Template Haskell has the [runIO](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.15.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v%3arunIO) function that lets you execute arbitrary things (such as reading and parsing a configuration file) at compile time; This is made slightly more accessible by the [file-embed](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/file-embed) package. This way, you can write your application in something like a `runAppWithConfig :: Configuration -> IO ()`, and then have two binaries that are basically just `main = readConfigFile >>= runAppWithConfig` or `main = runAppWithConfig embeddedConfig`. Or you can do both, with a default configuration being embedded but also allowing to override default options with command line parameters and what not.

[Yesod](https://www.yesodweb.com/) uses the approach of having compile time configurations a lot.

Of course alternatively you can also go a Haskell independent route and actually do create something similar to a .war by using something like [AppImage](https://appimage.org/) which is kind of a mix between self-extracting archive and an application.

But really, how to do configuration isn’t particularly language specific and there are many approaches on how to go about it. You could even leave your application as it is right now and just ship the configuration you want with it instead of just copying over the binary.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me a nice overview to start and quite a bit more stuff to look into :D